# Проблема с Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Во время изменения фокуса из `DataGrid` на кнопку срабатывает обновление привязки у `CurrentCell`

1. выбираю строку со столбцом срабатывает `Binding CurrentCell` (В VM обновляется `DatagridCellInfo`)
2. Нажимаю на кнопку срабатывает снова `Binding CurrentCell` (Как не дать срабатывать?)(В VM обновляется `DatagridCellInfo` на `null`), по коду вроде не должен (Хотя `updatesourcetotriger=propertychanged`) и потом

Мой XAML `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPlaneMonth}"
          IsReadOnly="{Binding Path=IsReadOnly}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          CurrentCell="{Binding Path=DataGridCell, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          ColumnWidth="*"/>
```

Мой Код VM на `CurrentCell`

```
public DataGridCellInfo DataGridCell
{
    get => _dataGridCell;
    set
    {
        _dataGridCell = value;
        OnPopertyChanged("DataGridCell");
        if (_dataGridCell.Column != null)
        {
            CheckBox content = _dataGridCell.Column.GetCellContent(_dataGridCell.Item) as CheckBox;
            if (content.IsChecked == true)
            {
                IsEnableButton = true;
            }
            else
            {
                IsEnableButton = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Мой код VM на Кнопку `ChangedCommand`

```
public PosukCommand ChangedCommand
{
    get
    {
        return _changedCommand ??
                (_changedCommand = new PosukCommand(obj =>
                {
                    if (_dataGridCell.Column != null)
                    {
                        using (PosukContext db = new PosukContext())
                        {
                            PprCalendarPalneMonth palneMonth = _dataGridCell.Item as PprCalendarPalneMonth;
                            var _day = palneMonth.GetType().GetField("Day" + _dataGridCell.Column.DisplayIndex.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }));
    }
}
```

Comment: Это не похоже на MVVM, суть MVVM в том, что View (благодаря встроенным в WPF привязкам и поддержке команд) привязывается к ничего не знающей об этом VM. Вы же в VM манипулируете какими-то контролами явно...

Comment: Можете дать подсказку, вроде делаю как по учебнику. View ничего не знает и все в VM обновляется через бинды